# Image Zoom and transformation with scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

i'm trying to replicate the animation at the center of the page of the https://www.theweeknd.com/ website (6/7 images that change resolution with a transform class) but i'm struggling to do that..

Anyone who knows how to do that or maybe point me in the right direction? I search on the web but i cannot find an animation like that (JS).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please alsways include a **minimal reproducible** example. Breaking the problem down will often help you to answer it yourself or to find more specific help. If you don't know on how to ask a good question, consult [How To Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

They change the translate3d property onmousewheel for the parent div.

[image]